# Get Div Element from same domain URL and append to new Div

Tags: jquery

What have i done wrong trying to use jQuery get to grab a div from another html page on my domain and append to a new div on another page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get('mysite.com').html(data).find('#currentDIV').appendTo('#newDIV');
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem i am having is i have 2 extensions for my site, so maybe using jQuery is out of the question. I need to pull some info from www and append to my www2 . I think jQuery get is not allowing for cross domain or something ? even though both are actually same domain , due to the different www extensions

http://www.mysite.com

http://www2.mysite.com

Got all above working thanks to the help here............

i am grabbing a tab from my other domain and recreating that tab

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newtabs').load('mysite.com #tab1')
});
```

so is it possible to append the #newtabs to open into a link ?

i grabbed #tab1 from my www.mysite  and recreated that tab text into www2.mysite , since i have it cloned , on the new site clicking the tab simply adds #1 to the current URL , how can i make it so when clicked it opens a full url i direct it to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) returns a promise object, not the value returned by the ajax request - so you need to use a success callback to use the returned value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('mysite.com', function (data) {
        $(data).find('#currentDIV').appendTo('#newDIV')
    });
});
```

If the `newDIV` element does not have any other content then you can use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newDIV').load('mysite.com #currentDIV')
});
```

Note: Make sure the site is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) enabled if you are working with different domains

Comment: great thanks .  I can't get it working though , i will update my post to show my issue

Comment: @user2200854 you can't do it unless as I said CORS is enabled in mysite.com since you are trying to access a cross domain request

Comment: ok great i enable CORS and got it working , however i am trying to pull some tabs from my other domain , and the URL is just adding #1,#2 when i click the new tab i appended to. Is is possible to append the #newDIV and have the tab link i pulled be linked to open ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have `});` twice? you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

Since calling [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) creates an asynchronous request you need to add a callback for when the request is finished; in other words, you can't chain `$.get`.

Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
$.get('mysite.com', function(data) {
    $('#currentDIV').append(data);
});
```